# Role Base Authorization with UseJwtBearerAuthentication on Net 4.7.2 WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, webapi

My desktop app call a Net WebApi using access token coming from keycloak. The Authorization attribute on my webapi running well but my WebApi it can't work with authorization. I tried to inject role claims but the api keep on error 401. Here is my Startup.cs

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Demo.Startup))]

namespace Demo
{
    public class CustomOAuthBearerProvider : OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task ValidateIdentity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext context)
        {
            var claims = context.Ticket.Identity.Claims; 
            context.Ticket.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Admin")); // injected claims here
            base.ValidateIdentity(context);
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }

    public partial class Startup
    {
        static string _realm = "myrealm";
        static string _authority = "http://localhost:8080/realms/myrealm";

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;

            var domain = _authority;
            var apiIdentifier = "account";
            var keyResolver = new OpenIdConnectSigningKeyResolver(domain);
            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication( 
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
                    {
                        ValidAudience = apiIdentifier,
                        ValidIssuer = domain.TrimEnd('/'),
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, kid, parameters) => keyResolver.GetSigningKey(kid),                      
                    },    
                    Provider = new CustomOAuthBearerProvider()
                });        

            System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
        }
}
```

My controller:

```
[Route("test")]
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public Strig Test()
{
   return "Hello";
}
```

test method always returning 401 eventhough I inject an Admin role from ValidateIdentity. The method working properly if i take out Roles decoration.

Comment: Inside TokenValidationParameters add RoleClaimType = ClaimTypes.Role and NameClaimType = ClaimTypes.Name

Comment: it works. just need improvement, where is the best place to tranform jwt role to user identity role?